# Relationships between custom tables and membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, database-design, asp.net-membership

I see lots of people say don't associate your tables to membership provider's table directly.

But this is the scenario how can I solve it:

- I use sqlmembershipprovider for membership.
- there are some offices which have personnel, `Doctors` and `Secretaries`.
- I have a table for `doctors` another for `secretaries`
- each doctor/secretary should have an
  account for signing in.

  ```
  public class Doctor
  {
      public Doctor()
      {
          this.Expertises = new HashSet<Expertise>();
      }

      [Key]
      public int DoctorId { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("Office")]
      public int OfficeId { get; set; }
      public virtual aspnet_Users User { get; set; }
      public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Expertise> Expertises { get; set; }
  }

  public class Secretary
  {
      [Key]
      public int SecretaryId { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }

      // the rest..

      [ForeignKey("Office")]
      public int OfficeId { get; set; }
      public virtual aspnet_Users User { get; set; }
      public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
  }
  ```

I thought I can make a relationship between doctor/secretary table to `user` table of membership provider, but this seems not a good approach.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** each employee (doctor or secretary) should have a registered account like other site's users to log in, it seems I shouldn't directly make a relationship between employee and membership tables, because maybe we later change the membership provider. So how can an employee has an account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have and Employee object.

```
        public class Employee
        {
            [Key]
            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            public string LastName { get; set; }

            // the rest..

            [ForeignKey("Office")]
            public int OfficeId { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("EmployeeType")]
            public int EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }

            public virtual aspnet_Users User { get; set; }

            public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
        }


public class EmployeeType
{ 
  [Key]
  public int EmployeeTypeId {get; set;}
  public string EmployeeTypeDescription {get; set;} // Doctor or whatever
}
```

Comment: sorry, I should provide more details, I edited my question. thank you.